# Japanese onomatopoeia for "Crash!"?

Tags: onomatopoeia

Specifically, a loud, violent crash. Like a car wreck.

Comment: What have you found so far? Have you tried a dictionary or website like https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/crash , https://japanese-lessons.net/Japanese/lessons/japanese-onomatopoeia-lesson.html , https://www.japanpowered.com/anime-articles/manga-sound-effect-guide

Comment: Like ガーン、ダーン、ドーン、バーン、ドガーン? There are too many to give a definite answer.